# Eclipse Cannot Open File

Tags: eclipse

Out of the blue Eclipse stopped opening one particular file. It's a class file, but other class files in the same JAR and package can be opened without a problem. The Java file corresponding to the class can be opened without a problem.

The error message is:

> Failed to create the part's controls

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceMapper.getUnqualifiedTypeSignature(SourceMapper.java:1308)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceMapper.getUnqualifiedMethodHandle(SourceMapper.java:1262)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceMapper.getSourceRange(SourceMapper.java:1191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryMember.getSourceRange(BinaryMember.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.computeProjectionRanges(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:1098)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.computeFoldingStructure(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:1026)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.computeFoldingStructure(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:976)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.computeFoldingStructure(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:980)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.computeFoldingStructure(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:967)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.update(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:884)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.initialize(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:829)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.handleProjectionEnabled(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:800)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider$ProjectionListener.projectionEnabled(DefaultJavaFoldingStructureProvider.java:681)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.fireProjectionEnabled(ProjectionViewer.java:488)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.enableProjection(ProjectionViewer.java:536)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaSourceViewer.setVisibleDocument(JavaSourceViewer.java:681)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setDocument(TextViewer.java:2934)
```

After loudly complaining about it other colleagues of mine told me they had had the same problem with other files, and "restarting Eclipse" / "clean and refresh orgy" / "creating a new workspace" / "installing a new Eclipse version" will not make the problem go away (I can only confirm the first three yet).

What could be the problem? How do I fix this? How can I prevent this in the future?

[This question looks similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707536/eclipse-failed-to-create-the-parts-controls-error-stringindexoutofboundsexc), but has a completely different stack trace. This is the [source of SourceMapper](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.tycho/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.11.0.v20150602-1242/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/SourceMapper.java?av=f#1308) (it doesn't help me).

Comment: @duffymo I wish I could, but we are developing SWT applications. ;(

Comment: What a shame.  Good luck.