# Groovy failures after upgrading eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, groovy-eclipse

Recently upgraded to Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0) and Groovy hasn't worked since.

Upgraded Groovy with no improvement.

Now running (expanding all the "What's installed" tree)

- Eclipse Groovy Development Tools     org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group
- Groovy Compiler 2.5 org.codehaus.groovy25.feature.feature.group
- Groovy-Eclipse Compilerless feature  org.codehaus.groovy.compilerless.feature.feature.group
- Groovy-Eclipse Headless feature  org.codehaus.groovy.headless.feature.feature.group
- Eclipse JDT Core patch for Groovy    org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group
- Groovy Compiler 3.0      org.codehaus.groovy30.feature.feature.group

All with version 4.0.0.v202012311505-e2009-RELEASE.  However, the entry for "Eclipse JDT Core patch for Groovy" has a red '+' overlaid on its plugin icon.

Referring to the Eclipse log,
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupport` is being reported constantly.  I'm assuming the patched JDT Core is not installed correctly but not sure what to do next.

Comment: You must use the update site that matches your eclipse release. You have eclipse 2020-12 and groovy tools 2020-09.

Answer (score 1):

For me I couldn't open groovy files, all I got was a blank editor pane. Initially I installed groovye-eclipse from eclipse market place.

@emilles comment was spot on. I did have an incorrect version installed. After uninstalling and adding new update site specific to my eclipse version (2020-12) it works fine. I can open and edit groovy files.