# Eclipse 2020-12 - I can't create or edit groovy classes (was OK in 2020-09)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

Recently Eclipse 2020-09 updated itself to 20200-12. My Java development has been OK. However, this evening, I needed to create a new Groovy class. The editor failed to open - I got an error 'window' (tltle = 'New') that said:

```
Creation of element failed. org/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/refactoring/core/utils/GroovyTypeBuilder
```

Opening an existing Groovy file results in the editor area being all grey and open editors have lost focus.
I've spent ages trying to find a solution - and failed.

If someone can help me with this, I'll be immensely grateful  as work on my product has ground to a halt!

BACKGROUND

The new-class action creates a .log file. At the end of the log the entry is

```
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/refactoring/core/utils/GroovyTypeBuilder
```

Further up the log, I've seen other 'no class def found' entries for:

- "org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupport"
  "org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupportFactory"
  "org/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/refactoring/formatter/GroovyIndentationService"

This is a Maven+Git project that produces a jar file.

Groovy complierversion is 2.5.14.

Maven dependency is groovy-xml-2.5.6,jar, which pulls in groovy-2.5.6,jar

I spent a long time at the start of 2020 working out the pom.xml so that the App's jar file and related folders+files all end up correctly. (I'm a Sunday-driver Maven guy, so once it worked, I was happy to leave it alone).

I really don't want to change versions of Groovy or anything - I don't think it's good practice to change 'infrasucture' in the middle of project.

As I don't know what other information will be helpful, I will provide it on request.

Comment: When eclipse was updated from 2020-09 to 2020-12, did you change the groovy-eclipse update site link?  GDT is matched with the JDT version that it patched by way of versioned update sites.

Comment: Here is a possibly similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65636091/8395666

Comment: @emiles. I can't thank you enough. Once Ihad figured out the probably url for the 2020-12 GDT AND I had removed the 2020-09 versions, it's all OK now. I had to remove the '09' GDT because Eclipse said they were more recent than the '12'!  John