# CoffeeBytes code folding gives nullpointerexception on eclipse

Tags: java

I've seen similar questions on stackoverflow asking for code folding for eclipse (all active many years ago). I've decided to use coffeebytes code folding and managed to get it working. But for some reason, certain times using coffeebytes results in eclipse giving a "Failed to create this part's controls" with a null pointer exception with infinite loop error in the errors section. I've experienced this multiple times. It happens when I try to write a static method in a class. This seems to only happen with *specific* methods, but I can't seem to know why. If I remove the method, it works fine. The code compiles and runs normally. I don't think I can post example code, since the file is very big and contains multiple methods. I've searched the web and found another user with the same problem, but no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Oh. While I was writing this question, I found the solution. I was going to delete this solution, but I hope that someone else in the future with the same problem can use this solution too. For some reason, coffeebytes does not allow you to use _ in a number, ex: "10_000". I just removed it and it worked. I got the inspiration from the last answer to:  [eclipse: 'failed to create the part's controls' error, StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707536/eclipse-failed-to-create-the-parts-controls-error-stringindexoutofboundsexc)

Comment: there's no issue replying to your own question, no worries there.